# Using Recyclerview like gridview

Tags: android

I am trying to use recyclerview like gridview. But i have a problem. Now my code works like this:

[image]

You see the numbers, they are wrong. It should be like this:

[image]

So i have to put photo#2 to right of the photo#1 etc.

How can i achive this?

My current code:

```
instagramProfileAdapter = new InstagramProfileAdapter(initGlide());
tempRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

tempRecycler.setAdapter(instagramProfileAdapter);
```

Comment: How would you like the scrolling to work in your case? When you move the grid to the left by one image, would you like the grid to display {first row: [2, 3, 4, 9]}, {second row: [6, 7, 8, 13]}?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do what you want using Horizontal GridLayoutManager,
But you can sort the list before add it into RecyclerView.

```
        val arr1  = arrayListOf(1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8)

        // arr1  = [1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8]

        val arrSorted = ArrayList<Int>()

        for (i in 0 until arr1.size) {
          if(i % 2 == 0) arrSorted.add(arr1[i])
        }

        for (i in 0 until arr1.size) {
            if(i % 2 != 0) arrSorted.add(arr1[i])
        }

        // arrSorted = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use other constructor of GridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount). By default, it use vertical orientation, possible it fix your trable.